# @angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq Disable or allow null

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint

Using Angular 12 & eslint, I've got an error in the template because I'm doing this:

```html
<button [disabled]="someVariable == null"></button>
```

> Expected `===` but received `==` eslint(@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq)

When going through the [source code](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-template/src/rules/eqeqeq.ts), I noticed an option called `allowNullOrUndefined`.

I tried to define the rule like this:

```json
"@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": [
    "error",
    {
        "allowNullOrUndefined": true
    }
]
```

But I still got the error. So I tried to completely disabled the rule, like this:

```json
"@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": ["off"]
```

or like this:

```json
"@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off"
```

But with no luck, I still get the error in the template.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding that rule. Can I disable it or allow double equal for null or undefined ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `== null`? If you do not care about the `null`, and disable the button whenever the `someVariable` has a truthy value, you could simply do `[disabled]="!someVariable"`

Comment: well.... indeed :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

2 years later! You were close. Add this to the HTML section of `.eslintrc.json` like so:

```
{
  "files": [
    "*.html"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": [
      "error",
      {
        "allowNullOrUndefined": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obviously make sure you have the right npm modules installed such as `@angular-eslint/template-parser`

These should already be installed if you used `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics --skip-confirmation` to install eslint into your Angular project.

Comment: This is correct but I'd like to insist on one important point for future viewers:
Do not add `*.html` to the existing `*.ts` in the `files` property, otherwise it will break TS files linting. I misunderstood the answer and spent some time on this until I realized there was a separate config for html below

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to highlight the rule as `warning` (yellow line) instead of an `error` (red line), simple modify the `*.html` overrides object like this:

```
{
  "files": ["*.html"],
  "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": ["warn"]
  }
}
```